# Static spin structure factor calculation for systems with large unit cells

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

How to calculate the static spin structure factor in a system with a large unit cell? I know the basic definition of it, however, I am not sure what change would happen for a large unit cell.

The static spin structure factor is a quantity of interest in condensed matter physics, which provides information about the spin correlations in a material. It is defined as the Fourier transform of the spin-spin correlation function:

\begin{equation}
S(\mathbf{q}) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i,j} \langle \mathbf{S}_i \cdot \mathbf{S}_j \rangle e^{i\mathbf{q} \cdot (\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_j)},
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{S}_i$ is the spin at site $i$, $\mathbf{r}_i$ is the position of site $i$, $\langle \cdot \rangle$ denotes the thermal average, $N$ is the total number of lattice sites, and $\mathbf{q}$ is the wave vector.

Any help or comment is highly appreciable!

Comment: Have you worked out the case for two sites in the unit cell? The case of large unit cells is a straight-forward generalization of that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. My main confusion here is, If I have a unit cell with two sites, should I consider the (i,j) summation over all the different unit cells and sites inside those unit cells or only the sum over different sites of a single unit cell?